# Problems with using entire screen with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this very simple layout, 
2 buttons, checkbox, seekbar and some text..
Its currently on LinearLayout and i can use only half of the screen, 5-6 rows max.
Im trying to drag the buttons to the buttom but i cant. its like they're stuck in a frame covering only upper-half of the screen. Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timerText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/statusText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/timerCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerTime"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="activateTimer"
        android:text="@string/timerCB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="stopOperation"
        android:text="@string/stop_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="startOperation"
        android:text="@string/start_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/timerText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/timerTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerText"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:max="90" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my logcat is this:

```
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.remoteswitch/com.example.remoteswitch.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at com.example.remoteswitch.MainActivity.allocatePointers(MainActivity.java:60)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at com.example.remoteswitch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-09 17:01:41.107: E/AndroidRuntime(12469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: Please show your some part of code...

Comment: I added the layout xml. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

For the outer LinearLayout have you tried

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Also can I ask why you choose

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

for your widgets? Is there a reason not to use "wrap_content" or a non-zero value?

Comment: Im not too much familiar with layout coding. I just tried to use it in the visualizing way, not the xml way. I removed 0dp lines and changed to wrap_content, even tough im not sure of its effect. I still cant move things as i wish

Comment: What do you mean, move things?

Comment: dragging buttons over the screen to my desired location. at the LinearLayout its like only the upper half of the screen can work. I tried to go back to Relative, which is a bit annoying because everything is dependant in the rest, but after locating what i want where i want, the app crashes. I uploaded the xml to main post. it says something wrong with checkbox, but i dont understand what exactly. all my changes i did in the layout view.